# Cross origin issue in react

Tags: .net, reactjs, frontend, backend

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend/API/MessagesBroadcast/Get/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the backend not in the front end..
to workaround it... make a proxy of this url if you do not own it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your backend API is restricting access from http://localhost:3000, due to CORS policy, to solve it, allow CORS on backend API. You can refer it further: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

This should be configured by the backend, it should allow the cross domains if you do not have the server access or backend access you can try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en) chrome extension and get your development going.